# Python raspberry Image.open image from request.get(url)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to open an image from an URL to then process the image.

The image I'm fetching comes from one raspberry cam through this endpoint

```
@app.route('/image')
def getImage():
    frame = video_camera.get_frame()
    return Response((b'--frame\r\n'
    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n'),
                       mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Then on another raspberry I'm trying to get the image this way:

```
 r = requests.get('http://'+ip+'/image') 
 curr_img = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```

If I open the link in the browser I can see the image, so that part seems to be okay.
But I still get this error when using Image.open:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0xffff8836dba0>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try printing/dumping the first 20 bytes of `r.content` to see if it looks like a JPEG.

Comment: it looks like this b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x02\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x04
and lot more of that basically

Comment: `PIL Image` is only going to like that from after the third `\r\n` onwards, i.e. starting `ff d8`

Comment: Thanks, you "pushed me" to the right direction :) removed the extra bytes and now it opens the image properlly

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to change my

```
@app.route('/image')
def getImage():
    frame = video_camera.get_frame()
    return Response((b'--frame\r\n'
    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n'),
                       mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

to

```
@app.route('/image')
def getImage():
    frame = video_camera.get_frame()
    return frame
```

My video_camera.get_frame() is already giving me the bytes of the image so I don't need to add nothing to it.